# Xcode universal application with one storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

How can we make a universal application in Xcode so that if the iPhone view has a table view the iPad has a collection view? I can't think of how we can do this using size classes.

Comment: If you want to go for a `UICollectionView` on iPad-sized screens, why not write a custom collection layout that would only allow one cell per row on iPhone-sized screens (and more cells per row for larger devices)? You'd keep yourself DRY this way...

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it.

- Add both UITableView and UICollectionView to your "one" universal story board.
- Connect  UITableView and UICollectionView using IBOutlets.
- Add both delegates to your *.h file
- Add delegate code for both views in *.m file.
- Use an if/else clause to see what device is running your app and depending upon the answer hide the view.

  ```
  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
  {    
      //its iphone, hide UICollectionView    
      //i.e. myCollectView.hidden=YES; 
  } 
  else 
  {    
      //its ipad, hide UITableView    
      //i.e. mytableView.hidden=YES; 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for size classes and auto layout.